# what is the use of setRequesterHeader for XmlHttpRequest in javascript

Tags: javascript

can u please explain why do we use accept and content type in `setRequestHeader`

```
req.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
req.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/json");
```

Answer (score 4):

`Accept` header specifies the format of the response you would like to receive, while `Content-Type` instruct the server about data format you've used to send data.

See section `14.1` and `14.17` of the [official specification](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616.txt).

Comment: xmlhttpRequest.setRequestHeader("SOAPAction", );....what is the pupose of this statement

Comment: This statement adds yet another header `SOAPAction` with some value. From HTTP protocol perspective it has absolutleny no meaning, however [SOAP protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOAP) build on top of the HTTP protocol uses it: https://www.w3.org/TR/2000/NOTE-SOAP-20000508/#_Toc478383528